# Windows Phone background task stops prematurely

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I'm developing a WP8.1 SL app which uses **background tasks** (not agents!).

My task is triggered by a TimerTrigger - once every 30 minutes (which I believe is the minimum interval for Windows Phone, right?). **It is doing a lot of work, and for some reason, sometimes it gets interrupted - that is, it stops in the middle of it.** The way I know it's in the middle of it is because I log what's happening and the task's work is basically the same every time.

I deployed the app to my device yesterday to test a new approach, and everything was working fine - the background task was doing everything every time it was started - worked like a charm. Today my device needed a soft reset, so I did it (nothing was working, it happens from time to time since I updated to WP8.1). Since that moment, the background task gets interrupted every time, right in the middle of it, just as with the previous approach.

Any ideas what can cause this? **I'm thinking it may be connected to the soft reset, because - 100% success rate before it, 0% after that.**

**What I've tried so far:**

- I'm logging errors, I have a try-catch around everything, I've subscribed to the UnobservedException event and to the task's Canceled event, and I'm logging the suspension count - none of these things help. There seem to be no errors, it's not suspended, and it's not canceled.
- I'm logging the current memory usage from time to time, and it's about 16-17MB. On my device, the limit should be 30MB, so I don't think that's a problem.
- I'm calling RequestAccessAsync wherever I can. I thought once should be enough, but since that soft-reset issue, i decided to put it in 1-2 other places to check if it's causing the issue. Well, it's not, or at least this didn't fix it.

**What I'm not sure about:**

- I have no idea how to check the CPU time my task has consumed. I can't find a good/reliable way to do so. Also, I can't find any info that would explain why the task would be stopped in the middle sometimes, and other times - it would work fine.

**Any ideas why my background task is sometimes stopped at the middle?** I'm really having a hard time determining how to fix/improve the app and will it work at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Uhhh, hard question, as in WP background tasks [have many limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) (you are probably aware of that :). The CPU quota is only 2 seconds - maybe this? Also have you called [RequestAccessAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccessasync.aspx)? Also are you transferring any data over net?

Comment: Maybe some tests: is there a difference when the phone is powered? Is there a chance you can run a stopwatch, and notify in LocalSettings the time while your task is running? Can you build a simple task and await in it more than 2 seconds and see if it was cancelled? Also I assume that you are obtaining defferal.

Comment: Hey @Romasz! :) Thanks for the suggestions. I'm aware of 3 limits - CPU (not sure how to check), memory (checked), data transfer (not used). I'm calling RequestAccessAsync often enough. The CPU constraint is for CPU time, not actual running time. When it's doing everything the task runs for 10-15seconds. Whether the phone is charging/on battery at 20%/100% does not seem to have any effect on the task's execution. And your assumption is correct - I am getting a deferral and calling the Complete method at the end (in a finally block).

Comment: Few more - is your `Run` asynchronous? Have you tried to subscribe to Competed/Canceled events put there a method saving something in LocalSettings to indicate the problem? Is there any CPU consuming operation (I also don't know how to measure CPU)? If there is, maybe there is a chance to slow down it a little (Task.Delay(50).Wait())? Is there a chance that you share a code or simple example with the problem?

Comment: @Romasz The run itself is not async, but it calls an async method which uses a deferral as it should. I haven't tried the Completed event, the other one does not seem to be raised. It is CPU consuming, I can slow it down, but I don't know how that would help? At the moment I can't share code as the task uses several custom libraries. I'd guess its the CPU constraint that is my problem, but I don't know how to measure it and I don't understand why it was okay and then, after the soft reset it stopped working.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird thing that it stopped working. I'm not sure how you get the deferral - try to get it before calling await, hence when code hits await it will try to get out from Run method and call Completed event. It would be much easier if you could simplify your example and post it somewhere. Maybe slowing down the CPU will help as the CPU wouldn't be so much overloaded, I think there should be some limit time/overload when your Task is being killed - just for test - slow down (maybe disable some parts) and see if that helped.

Comment: I did a quick test with a for loop logging the datetime.now to a log file. I noticed that the background task approximately runs for about 9 minutes and exits.

Comment: @golldy did you put a Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep or something like that in the loop? Also, on what device did you test this?

Comment: No. i did not have any delay or sleep setup in my code. I have checked this on Nokia 929 and samsung huron as well.

Comment: @Romasz Slowing down did not help. :( Also, async methods don't automatically switch threads. I get the deferral before the first switch (otherwise it would run for a much shorter period - I've tested that. :)). I know sample code helps, but I can't do it right now. :/

Comment: I'm running our of ideas, if I have some time during the upcoming weekend, I will try to reproduce the problem. Also few questions: have you tried to monitor with Profiler or Windows Developer Power Tools? And try one simple thing - run your backgroundtask sychronously (if possible) - try to Wait() for your async methods.

Comment: I am having the same problem.
It's worth checking both the IBackgroundTaskInstance.SuspendedCount and the BackgroundWorkCost.CurrentBackgroundWorkCost.
If you can reproduce the issue on Windows, you can check in Event Viewer for all sort of goodies relating to background tasks.

Comment: @yasen HI, sorry for delay, but I had busy weekend. I've tried to play with CPU usage in the backgroundtask - [little example](http://1drv.ms/1jxVdx4). As I've checked in Windows Phone Developer Power Tools, my task is taking one core of the CPU (50% of usage over 15 senconds). I've tried to run in debugger mode and in release on the device. What is weird that my task doesn't get killed even it uses CPU for more than 2 seconds. Check it, maybe it will help.

Comment: Background tasks(at least in Windows 8 I assume it is the same for WP8.1) are allocated 2 sec every 15 mins, you can go over it if there is time left in the global pool however you can not depend on it. It's discussed in the white paper found here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411

Comment: @TimChard Thanks for the info (and sorry I didn't respond in so much time)! I know about these, but I couldn't identify the problem using them. Anyway, I just posted what solved my problem. You can check it out and share your thoughts on it.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks for the help. I appreciate it. I wasted too much time researching this, so I just had to do something else for a while. Sorry I didn't reply earlier. I think I found out why sometimes the tasks are running for more than expected. It seems that in some cases, the constraints are just not applied (even though they should be, I think). I posted an answer, you can check it out. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I think I found what my problem was.

First of all, the background task just needed a lot of CPU time, more than the limit, and that's why it was getting killed in the middle.

The reason why it was working sometimes, was because **sometimes the device on which I was testing treated the app as being in debug (or with attached debugger)**. In this case the restriction on CPU time is removed.

So, even if I uninstall the app and rebuild it in Release and redeploy, and start it without the debugger attached, the device was NOT enforcing the constraints. That only happens, if I have started the app with the debugger at least once (or maybe the first time) after it's deployed. Restarting the device (just power off and then turn on) fixes this.

While I was testing, using the same build of an app, its background task ran for **40 MINUTES** on one device, and just 3-4 seconds on another. After I restarted the first device, the background task started behaving normally (running for just a few seconds).

**So, if you want to test your background task for the CPU constraint:**

1. You must be testing on a device, not on the Emulator.
2. Uninstall the app, if it's installed.
3. Restart the device.
4. Deploy a Release build of the app.
5. Run the app, so that it can register the background task, and then close it.
6. Wait for the background task to be invoked. (You could add a trigger that can be forced, like TimeZoneChanged or UserPresent, so that you could quickly test it.)

P.S. This may not be the perfect answer, but these are my observations, and they helped me solve my problem. This by far is the best method I have found for testing the CPU time, and it's far from perfect. So, if anyone has better ideas, please share them.

Comment: It must be hard to find this out. Thanks for the information. Have you checked by a cahnce, if the constrain is connected with CPU usage time or it's counted from the beginning of the Task? For example you Run a task and do `await Task.Delay(20000);` (of course somewhere the deferral) - will it be killed or the code after will be run?

Comment: @Romasz It is connected to the CPU usage (so it's best to test with low-end devices, just in case :)). After 5 minutes though the task gets canceled as being "Idle". The Canceled event is raised with this reason. So, it could run normally for about 5 minutes, if it does not use too much CPU time and uses a lot of `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Thanks for the info - yeah it may be a nice pitfall with low-end devices. I wonder if it would be possible to put some kind of Timer that would be invoked for example in 3 minute interval to extend the Task's live - I'll have to build a simple example. Thanks once again for those usefull information.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Run method codes are not working even though it enters on the Run method. After it abruptly exits from the loop. Bit for the same bg task, I created  a sample project and it works fine. I cannot find the reason.