# background task timeline in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I am using the background task for a various features in the application. No where in the MSDN documentation, i see how long it runs.

For example in windows phone 8 sdk, periodic agents used to run for 25 seconds. is there a specific amount that the background task  runs for ?

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFile TimeLogFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("TimeLog.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(TimeLogFile, "Start Logging " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(TimeLogFile, "Beginning of Background Task " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(TimeLogFile, "During Background Task Execution " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
}
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(TimeLogFile, "End Logging " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the info you're looking for: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056(v=win.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

Basically, a background task can only use the CPU for 2 seconds each time it's started. It can however be active for a longer period, if it doesn't do CPU intensive work. If you await something slow that does not use the CPU too much, you can get to several minutes of execution.

Comment: Goes back to your question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166534/windows-phone-background-task-stops-prematurely?noredirect=1#comment37348441_24166534

Comment: @golldy Can you share the code that runs for 10 minutes? That is quite long. Also, did you test it in Release, without debugging? Also, aren't these docs the info you want? (Just so I know what you're looking for. :))

Comment: Checkout the edit that i have made.This is all i am doing. Simple long number loop.

Comment: @golldy You didn't answer my other questions :) Please do (answer all of them). I just tested it on the device I test, in Release, without debugging, and it is only running for about 3-4 seconds. :?

Comment: Testing in release no. I did not do that. Also....3 to 4 seconds ? If you are using the sample code, then it might be because it still has 
//_periodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(new TimerElapsedHandler(PeriodicTimerCallback), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

Comment: @golldy The code you've shared in the questions does not have that? But seriously, you should test in Release without debugging (the second one being more important). In other situations some of the constraints do not apply. Also, if the app is in the foreground, most of the constraints do not apply.

Comment: Yes. i agree that if the app is in the foreground all these constraints wont apply.

So according to you how long will the background task run for ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55593/discussion-between-yasen-and-golldy).